# How do you achieve a stress test in Gatling?

Tags: stress-testing, gatling

I am attempting to find the upper bounds of each endpoint our application provides. The test I am trying to build can be worded as such...

"For endpoint **{Z}**, start at **{A}** users at once then add **{B}** users every **{C}** seconds **UNTIL** error rate is **{D}** percent."

My biggest struggles are the [injections](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/general/simulation_setup.html#injection) and the completion condition. It appears I might have to build a custom injection since none of the prebuilt seem to satisfy my needs and I have not seen anything close to a completion condition.

Note: The [Assertion API](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/general/assertions.html) is not helpful in completing the test once the error rate is matched since it only inspects the outcome of a completed test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. However, this feature is in the roadmap of our upcoming commercial product.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what part isn't possible? That type of injection, the completion condition, or both?

Comment: That type of injection is not available built-in, and you don't have access to the live stats.

Comment: Sad :( but it answers my question.